# Why user selection is rendered on the screen?

Tags: javascript, browser, range, selection, w3c

I'm trying to pragmatically create the user selection. [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nvtZsyNLBl0hDFlkhqIU?p=preview). Here is the simple setup:

```
<p>Tim O'Reilly calls for a Blogger Code of Conduct. His proposals are:</p>
<ol>
    <li>Take responsibility not just for your own words, but for the
        comments you allow on your blog.</li>
    <li>Label your tolerance level for abusive comments.</li>
    <li>Consider eliminating anonymous comments.</li>
</ol>

<script>
    var range = document.createRange();
    var startPar = document.querySelector('p').firstChild;
    var endLi = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)').firstChild;
    range.setStart(startPar,13);
    range.setEnd(endLi,17);
    console.log(range.toString());
</script>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, I get the expected output to console, however the text is not selected on the screen. Is it by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the range, but now you need to tell the browser to select it. Example:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Comment: thanks, that was the bit that was missing. I tried to not remove the currently selected range by `removeAllRanges`, it doesn't work without that. Do you know why? see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ce0VcDZVwzHJguegZoyu?p=preview) - select something on the screen and wait 3 seconds

Comment: I don't think browsers generally support multiple selection ranges (see [description about multiple ranges](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcpcpnt.php)). Instead what you can do is get the existing selection range and modify it. To get the range, use `var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);`.

Comment: This [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) for the `Range` object might help you extend/modify your range and then you can use `removeAllRanges()` and `addRange()` again to make the resulting selection.

Comment: cool, thanks. I read that `selection` is redundant since it can contain only one range